# Any Haxe GC tips?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, garbage-collection, haxe

Recently I am learning Haxe for Flash, and I have some ActionScript 3 experience.

I notice there is a `delete` operation in AS3, Is there something like `delete` in Haxe? Is the `delete` about GC? Are there any tips for Haxe newbies about memory management?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marcus already explained what the `delete` operator does. For use in Haxe please refer to [this page](http://old.haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic).

Thus the Haxe equivalent of `delete foo.b` is `untyped __delete__(foo, "b")`. In case you intend to use it a lot, I suggest you put that into a function ;)

Answer (score 10):

I don't really know much about Haxe, but the `delete` operator in AS3 actually doesn't delete objects. You can't force deconstruction in AS3 at all really. The `delete` operator is used to remove the reference to a property of a dynamic object. For example:

```
var foo:Object {
    a: "Hello, ",
    b: "world!",
    toString: function () { return a + b; }
}

foo.toString() // Hello, world!
```

This anonymous object is dynamic and properties can be added or removed. Much like a hash table. Now consider the following:

```
delete foo.b;
foo.toString(); // Hello, undefined
```

When the delete occurs, `foo` releases its reference to the property `b`, making it `undefined`. The value of `b` however is not necessarily removed from memory. If someone else is referencing the same value, it will most likely stick around. Thus, `delete` only removes references, not actual values and as such will not enable you to force garbage collection.